# How to queue new URL when exception occurs in Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

Suppose that before I launch my Scrapy crawler, I am not sure if a site is served via `HTTPS` or `HTTP`. So I always try `HTTPS` first (e.g., https://www.wsiltv.com/random) using the code as follows:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror import HttpError
from twisted.internet.error import DNSLookupError, ConnectionRefusedError

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "myspider"

    def __init__(self, category=None):
        self.failed_urls = []

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = ['https://www.WSILTV.COM/random', # a few more URLs here
               ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse,
                                 meta={'dont_redirect': True},
                                       errback=self.err_callback)

    def parse(self, response):
        cur_datetime = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
        yield {'text':response.body, 'fetch_date':cur_datetime}

    def err_callback(self, failure):
        # REF: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#using-errbacks-to-catch-exceptions-in-request-processing
        if failure.check(HttpError):
            # I want to record URLs that caused HTTP errors
            self.failed_urls.append([failure.value.response.url, failure.value.response.status])
            return
        elif failure.check(DNSLookupError):
            # Similarly, I'd like to record those which caused DNS errors
            # E.g., 'https://non-existent-url.com'
            self.failed_urls.append([failure.request.url, 'DNSLookupError'])
            return
        elif failure.check(ConnectionRefusedError):
            # Here, I'd like to try HTTP version of the original URL such as 'http://www.WSILTV.COM/random'
            new_request = Request('http://www.WSILTV.COM/random', callback=self.parse, meta={'dont_redirect': True})
        else:
            return
```

In other words, I'd like to know how to queue a new request (to crawl) from `err_callback` method. Also, is there a better (more efficient) way to try `https` first and then if it fails, try `http` later in Scrapy?

Thank you in advanced for your answers!

Comment: Try adding `handle_httpstatus_list = [404, 500, 502]` to your scraper and handle the errors in `parse` itself

Comment: @TarunLalwani the problem is that even if I make `meta = {'dont_redirect': True,'handle_httpstatus_list': [404, 500, 502]}`, the crawler would never enter `parse()`. Instead, it goes to `err_callback`. I need to handle other errors inside `err_callback` as shown above. Thank you for your suggestion though.

Comment: For those you can use `301`, `302` also in the list. I will see if something else is there

Comment: @TarunLalwani Thank you. I removed `err_callback` but the code would not enter 'parse()`, so I cannot do anything there... Please share if you find anything promising. Thanks again!

Comment: Try adding `self.crawler.engine.crawl(new_request, self.crawler.spider)` to crawl the new request

Comment: @TarunLalwani Could you share a link to some tutorial how to add `self.crawler.engine.crawl`? Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167914/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-user1330974).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify your

```
elif failure.check(ConnectionRefusedError):
   # Here, I'd like to try HTTP version of the original URL such as 'http://www.WSILTV.COM/random'
   new_request = Request('http://www.WSILTV.COM/random', callback=self.parse, meta={'dont_redirect': True})
else:
```

Like below

```
elif failure.check(ConnectionRefusedError):
   # Here, I'd like to try HTTP version of the original URL such as 'http://www.WSILTV.COM/random'
   new_request = Request('http://www.WSILTV.COM/random', callback=self.parse, meta={'dont_redirect': True})
   self.crawler.engine.crawl(new_request, self.crawler.spider)
else:
```

This will add the request to the queue from the error handler

Comment: Thank you very much for sticking with me and providing a viable solution! This works and would be a way for me to overcome updating the URLs in Scrapy. :)